# Alternative terms for meaning "wake up"

Tags: synonyms

What other terms or expressions can be used to say "wake up", either slang or not?

I have read about "quake up", but as English is not my natural language I am not sure of how used is this expression.

Can you list other expressions?

Comment: Are you looking for the transitive verb (what you do to someone who's sleeping) or the intransitive one (what you do when you stop sleeping)?

Comment: I am looking for a transitive verb.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of  the alternatives that you can use (if you use 'wake up' in the sense 'wake someone up').

1. Awake
2. Rouse

Or if you want to use it as in "I wake up", you can say,

1. Get up
2. Stir

I am not sure I have heard of 'quake up', but these might be others who are familiar with the term.

Answer (score 2):

You can say:

Get up  (I got up.  Go get your sister up.)

Rise (I will rise at 10 AM.  Not common.)

Rise and shine  (Rise and shine, sleepyhead! This is exclusively said about someone else, never yourself.)

Wake up   (I woke up around 10 AM)

Arise (I arose around 10 AM)

Get out of bed  (I got out of bed at 10 AM)

Rouse  (I roused around 10 AM)

Answer (score 1):

*Wake up* is right and works in most contexts. If it's decidedly informal I might use:

**Get up**: "It's time to get up, sleepyhead!" (Note in an intransitive context it could be interpreted as referring to physically getting out of bed, not necessarily the act or moment of awakening from sleep; e.g., "I woke up at seven but just *got up* a little while ago.".)

Comment: but what alternative forms would you use to make someone stop sleeping?

Comment: "Get up!", "Wake up!" or (as @rest_day suggests) "Rouse yourself! would all definitely be correct. "Hey, get up!" is probably what I'd expect someone to say.

Answer (score 1):

For the transitive case, "wake" works as well as "wake up", as in "go wake your father; it's time for dinner".

Comment: Ah, but what if he's dead?  [We can still wake him!](http://www.amazon.com/Waking-Ned-Devine-Ian-Bannen/dp/B00000ILEC)

Answer (score 1):

Some of my favorite morning phrases come from reading the [Horatio Hornblower](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_1_31?url=search-alias=stripbooks&field-keywords=horatio%20hornblower%20complete%20set&x=0&y=0&sprefix=horatio%20hornblower%20complete%20set#/ref=nb_sb_noss?url=search-alias=stripbooks&field-keywords=horatio%20hornblower&rh=n:283155,k%3ahoratio%20hornblower) and [Aubrey/Maturin](http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_1_31?url=search-alias=stripbooks&field-keywords=horatio%20hornblower%20complete%20set&x=0&y=0&sprefix=horatio%20hornblower%20complete%20set#/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_0_21?url=search-alias=stripbooks&field-keywords=aubrey%20maturin%20series&sprefix=aubrey%20maturin%20series&rh=n:283155,k%3aaubrey%20maturin%20series) series of books about the British Navy during the Napoleonic wars:

**Get your cold feet on the warm deck!**  (Who could resist such an offer?)

**Out or down!  Here I come, with a sharp knife and a clear conscience!** (If a sailor was too slow getting out of his hammock, his hammock would be cut down - dumping him on the deck.)